# Seaborn violinplot split requires arbitrary "y" value

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

In seaborn, I want to plot a single horizontal violin plot. In my tests so far, I've had to specify a dummy value as a constant column to use as the y value. Is there a simpler approach? It seems like a hack, but I can't seem to get the desired behavior without including a y argument.

Thanks in advance!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def generate_dataframe() -> pd.DataFrame:

    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['rand'])

    # normal variable
    df['rand'] = np.random.normal(size=(100,))

    # split by dummy
    df['ind'] = 'a'
    df['ind'].iloc[50:] = 'b'

    # I wouldn't think this would be needed
    df['y'] = "uhh"

    print(df)

    return df


def standard_violin_doesnt_work():

    plt.figure()

    # define dataframe
    df = generate_dataframe()
    sns.violinplot(x='rand', split=True, hue='ind', data=df)

    plt.show()
```

[image]

```
def standard_violin_does_work():

    plt.figure()

    # define dataframe
    df = generate_dataframe()
    sns.violinplot(x='rand', y='y', split=True, hue='ind', data=df)

    plt.show()
```

[image: I guess this isnt bad?]

Comment: There is [a comment](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/f0349b1a7f1e022cb1da8b94f2e019f04eeed397/seaborn/categorical.py#L177) in the code inside the `if x is None or y is None:` condition, saying `# This plot will not have group labels or hue nesting`. This means, if you want hue-nesting, you need to provide both `x` and `y` argument. It's unclear to me why that would be necessary, but your workaround is probably the best you can get at.